# Compressed Sparse Row (CSR): How do you store empty rows?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, sparse-matrix

How do you represent empty rows in CSR?

Suppose we have the following matrices:

```
* MATRIX 1 *
a 0 0
0 b 0
0 0 c

val = [ a b c ]
col = [ 0 1 2 ]
row = [ 0 1 2 ] <- makes sense!

—————————————————————   

* MATRIX 2 *
a b c
0 0 0
0 0 0

val = [ a b c ]
col = [ 0 1 2 ]
row = [ 0 ] <— makes sense…? but how about…

—————————————————————

* MATRIX 3 *
0 0 0
a b c
0 0 0

val = [ a b c ]
col = [ 0 1 2 ]
row = [ 0 ] <— wait… how do we differentiate between MATRIX 2 and MATRIX 3?
```

`MATRIX 1` is intuitive, but how do we represent the difference between `MATRIX 2` and `MATRIX 3`? Do we use a negative integer for spacing?

Thanks

Comment: What language/tool do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm asking about the theory in general. If it helps, C would be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29). The `IA` vector (or as you call it "row"), is defined as:

> The array IA is of length m + 1. It is defined by this recursive definition:
>
> - IA[0] = 0
> - IA[i] = IA[i − 1] + (number of nonzero elements on the (i − 1)-th row in the original matrix)
> - Thus, the first m elements of IA store the index into A of the first nonzero element in each row of M *[ ed: but only for rows that have at least one such element, i.e. IA[i+1]>IA[i] ]*, and the last element IA[m] stores NNZ, the number of elements in A, which can be also thought of as the index in A of first element of a phantom row just beyond the end of the matrix M. The values of the i-th row of the original matrix is read from the elements A[IA[i]] to A[IA[i + 1] − 1] (inclusive on both ends), i.e. from the start of one row to the last index just before the start of the next.

Thus, in Matrix 1:

`row = [0 1 2 3]`

in Matrix 2:

`row = [0 3 3 3]`

in Matrix 3

`row = [0 0 3 3]`

Answer (score -1):

The answer provided is close to being a great explanation but needs to be clarified a bit:

The first two bullet points give a clear prescription for the entries in `IA`.

But the next part,

"Thus, the first `m` elements of `IA` store the index into `A` of the first nonzero element in each row of `M`, and the last element `IA[m]` stores `NNZ`, the number of elements in `A`, which can be also thought of as the index in `A` of first element of a phantom row just beyond the end of the matrix `M`. The values of the `i-th row` of the original matrix is read from the elements `A[IA[i]] to A[IA[i + 1] − 1]`
(inclusive on both ends), i.e. from the start of one row to the last index just before the start of the next."

It is difficult to parse, because the references `"IA", "m", "NNZ", "M",` and `"A"` are not defined.

Is the length of `"IA"` equal to one plus the number of nonzero elements in the full matrix?. I think that `"A"` and `"M"` refer to the full matrix and the sparse matrix, but there isn't enough information to determine which is which. `"NNZ"` may refer to the number of nonzero elements in the full matrix. And "m" may be the same as `"NNZ"`.

Would you mind completing the explanation by providing the definitions of `"IA", "m", "NNZ", "M"` and `"A"`?

Thanks in advance, it would be much appreciated!