# Compressed Row Storage how to save number of columns

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, sparse-matrix

With the **Compressed Row Storage** method, sparse matrices can be stored efficiently.

After reading different sources I could not find out how the **number of columns** of a **n x m matrix** is stored.

Although the maximum of *col_ind* suggests to be the number of columns, there seems to be no way to ensure that the last column(s) of the matrix is/are not empty.

**How to store an n x m matrix if the last column consist entirely of zeros?**
(empty rows can be stored by a [repeating value in rowPtr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771387/compressed-sparse-row-csr-how-do-you-store-empty-rows).)

Example 2 x 3 matrix:

```
(1 2 0)
(2 1 0)
```

Encoded CRS:

```
col_ind = [1,2,1,2]
val = [1,2,2,1]
row_ptr = [1, 3]
```

Decoded again:

```
(1 2) // 3rd column lost
(2 1)
```

Comment: The matrix object should have an additional `shape` attribute.